# Adding parentheses in a loop when appending to a list in python

Tags: python, list, loops, for-loop, append

I have two lists:

```
one = ['a','b','c','d']
two = ['d', 'c',' b', 'a']
```

I would like to create a loop that produces the following output:
`[('a', d'), ('b', 'c'), ('c','b'), ('d', 'a')]`

This is my current code but it is not properly adding the parentheses.

```
final_list = []
for i in range(len(a)):
    final_list.append(a[i])
    final_list.append(b[i])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking for a list of `tuple`s, `zip` will do it for you

```
final_list = [t for t in zip(one, two)]
# [('a', 'd'), ('b', 'c'), ('c', 'b'), ('d', 'a')]
```

Or as suggested you can also do it without the explicit loop

```
final_list = list(zip(one, two))
```

Comment: Or just: `final_list = list(zip(one, two))`

Comment: Why stop there? `final_list = [*zip(one, two)]`

Answer (score 1):

Append tuples in the `for` loop:

```
for i in range(len(a)):
    final_list.append((a[i],b[i]))
```